# make command does not work in VM

Tags: makefile, rubygems

I am trying to install Jellyfish for my bioinformatics analysis on my Ubuntu virtual machine and as one of the last step in installing, I constantly get this error:

Could not find make (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)

```
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `<main>'
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to get rid of this issue.

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - /home/amir/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: Maybe `make` is not installed on your system?  If you run `make --version` from the command line do you get _command not found_?  If so try running `sudo apt-get install make` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment but when I tried install make, I'm getting this message:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
make is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

Comment: Then it's already installed (did you run `make --version` as I suggested?  Did it say _command not found_?)  If it's installed and the `--version` option works (shows you the version of make) then the title of your question "Make does not work" is wrong; there's nothing wrong with `make`: it works fine.  However, some aspect of Ruby gems is not able to invoke it; that's a Ruby/gems problem.